# Markov Chain for a teleportation machine

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am given the following problem:

Every time I teleport, the teleportation machine decides to transport me to the very same place I am with probability $α ∈ (0,1)$, or, if I don't repeat the same location, it randomly select one of the other $N−1$ places to which I can teleport and places me there instead. Find the limiting probability
$$
\lim_{n→∞}
P(\text{nth teleportation place is the same as the first place})
$$
I am also given the following hint: Deﬁne a suitable two state Markov Chain with states {initial place, other place}.

I approach the problem in the following way: Let $X_n = 0$ be the state in which we are at the initial place. Let $X_n = 1$ be the state in which we are at other place. Then the transition matrix is partially given by
$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1-\alpha \\
\beta & 1-\beta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, I can't seem to find $\beta$. I tried used Bayes' rule and conditional probability but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in another place, the probability you come back to the initial place is 
the probability you do not stay still $(1-\alpha)$ multiplied by the probability the initial place is chosen $\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)$, so

$$\beta = \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1}$$